# Why do mosquitoes not collect blood after platelets activate?

Tags: entomology

This may be anecdotal...

The Indian sub-continent is in the rainy part of summer. It follows the mosquito population goes up.

So when I sliced my palm, I expected the mosquitoes to collect there in force. Yet whilst they continued to go about their business on the forearms, face and elsewhere - the blood flowing out of my palm held no attraction for them. This even after I deliberately stood still for nearly a minute! Perhaps the clotting process/platelets/etc were a repellent.

Why do mosquitoes not collect blood after platelets activate?

Comment: I guess mosquitoes rarely have the opportunity to have available fresh blood. Therefore they did not evolve to recognize blood smell but only sweat smell (skin colors and animal shape). In other words, even if they had the physiology to take advantage of your injury, they are just not adapted to recognize it as an opportunity because they did not evolve for this purpose.

Comment: I do not know why they wouldn't *try*, but there may also be a physical reason why they would not: once platelets are activated, a clot might form and block their alimentary tract.

Comment: I just went to an interesting talk about malaria and asked the speaker about this. I will try to source and write an answer, but it would seem that mosquitoes can't detect the flowing blood vs the host (as @Rami.b pointed out).  The cut was probably small enough that there was low chance of the mosquitoes landing there vs the rest of your body.  They seem to be attracted to other excretions we produce constantly.

Comment: Here's an interesting publication: http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.cell.2013.12.044